# A better definition of "median"?

Tags: statistics, median

Referring to the definition in Wikipedia, paraphrased:

> Formally, a median of a population is any value such that at most half
> of the population is less than the proposed median and at most half is
> greater than the proposed median. As seen above, medians may not be
> unique. If each set contains less than half the population, then some
> of the population is exactly equal to the unique median.
>
> If the data set has an odd number of observations, the middle one is
> selected. For example, the following list of seven numbers,
>
> If the data set has an even number of observations, there is no
> distinct middle value and the median is usually defined to be the
> arithmetic mean of the two middle values

But  as all you statisticians know, this can lead to misdirection.  Consider the following dataset ( `R` code)

```
foo <- rnorm(1000)
bar <- rnorm(1001,50)
median(c(foo,bar))
[1] 46.86411
```

But the graph shows how bad a choice that is:

```
hist(c(foo,bar), breaks=100)
```

[image: histogram of bi-peak data]

Clearly we'd be better off picking the arithmetic mean of the max of the low peak and the min of the high peak.  Is this just a case of "look at the data before deciding which statistical parameters matter"?  Is there a reason the strict definition of 'median' fails to produce a useful value here?

Comment: You can always draw up examples like this. Consider any set where the two "middle numbers" are far apart. Then the median will always be their average.

Comment: Summary statistical measures inevitably throw away a whole lot of information.  Of course, if you have more information regarding the distribution you can use that extra information to better describe the data you are working on.

Comment: "Clearly we'd be better off..." Why is that clear? Better for what? You say the median fails to produce a useful value here: again, useful to what end? It looks like it's telling you exactly what it should: half of your data is above $46.86411$, and half is below. If that's not useful, then it's not the median's fault.

Comment: You answer your own question when you say "look at the data ...".

Comment: Your "the arithmetic mean of the max of the low peak and the min of the high peak" may not be satisfactory if the distribution is not symmetric.

Comment: More than half your data is from `bar`, so it is no surprise that the median is within the range of `bar`.  Here you might feel the mean is better mean of central tendency - if so use that.

Comment: @Henry yes, that was intentional so as to show how the default definition fails in this case